# Can't compile inline function with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Since the Kotlin update I can't compile my inline functions. Sometimes it compiles, but mostly it's just stuck at Gradle building.

```
inline fun <reified T> verifyAndPerformRequest(myRequest: MyRequest, 
header: Map<String, String>, crossinline callback: (Any?, error: 
Error?) -> Any?) {}
```

This a example of the functions that I can't compile. I am running the latest Android 3.1 + Kotlin 1.2.30

> [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error on build.

is the error message.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. Please try to update to the latest Kotlin version (1.2.40), and if it persists, report it to [kotl.in/issue](https://kotl.in/issue) (please attach the full stacktrace from the build log).

Comment: I tried it with Kotlin 1.2.30 and 1.2.40 in a minimal project and could not reproduce it. If you can share a sample project that fails to build due to this error, please do so.

Comment: @hotkey Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes, I have, and it compiles just fine for me, as well as a call of such a function.

Comment: Im very sorry guys for such a late response. It was a bug in the kotlinCopiler. It always finished the compile but since I was where sending a generics inside two inline functions it was taking a long time. I will try to minimize the code and send it to the kotlin crew and share it, if anyone is interested. I would upvote you all since all of your comments are relevant.